# ggplot not respectig order of colours in scale_fill_manual()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I am creating some violin plots and want to colour them. It works for a matrix of dimension 9, as in my previous question

[ggplot violin plot, specify different colours by group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50645517/8384166)

but when I increase the dimension to 15, the order of the colours are not respected. Why is this happening?

**Here it works (9 columns):**

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- matrix(rnorm(250*9),ncol=9)

# Violin plots for columns
mat <- reshape2::melt(data.frame(dat), id.vars = NULL)

mat$variable_grouping <- as.character(sort(rep(1:9,250)))



pp <- ggplot(mat, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variable_grouping)) + 
  geom_violin(scale="width",adjust = 1,width = 0.5)  + scale_fill_manual(values=rep(c("red","green","blue"),3))
pp
```

**Here it does not work (15 columns):**

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- matrix(rnorm(250*15),ncol=15)

# Violin plots for columns
mat <- reshape2::melt(data.frame(dat), id.vars = NULL)

mat$variable_grouping <- as.character(sort(rep(1:15,250)))



pp <- ggplot(mat, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variable_grouping)) + 
  geom_violin(scale="width",adjust = 1,width = 0.5)  + scale_fill_manual(values=rep(c("red","green","blue"),5))
pp
```

Comment: Your `variable_grouping` variable is converted to a factor by ggplot and so uses the default level order (where `1` comes before `2`).  If you want to control the order of the factor levels you'll need to set the levels yourself "by hand".  I use `forcats::fct_inorder()` for this because it's convenient, a la `fill = forcats::fct_inorder(variable_grouping)`.

Comment: @aosmith That works. I will accept it if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is related to [setting factor levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199274/how-to-force-specific-order-of-the-variables-on-the-x-axis).  Since `variable_grouping` is a character, **ggplot2** converts it to a factor for plotting. It uses the default factor order, where `1` always comes before `2`.  So in your example 11-15 all come before 2 in the legend.

You can manually set the factor order to avoid the default order.  I use `forcats::fct_inorder()` for this because it's convenient in this case where you want the order of the factor to match the order of the variable.  Note you can also use `factor()` directly and set the level order via the `levels` argument.

```
ggplot(mat, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = forcats::fct_inorder(variable_grouping))) + 
     geom_violin(scale="width", adjust = 1, width = 0.5)  + 
     scale_fill_manual(values=rep(c("red","green","blue"),5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also name the color vector. For example:

```
my_values <- rep(c("red","green","blue"),5)
names(my_values) <- rep(c("Data1","Data2","Data3"),5)


... +
  scale_fill_manual(values=my_values)
```